# How to align form elements side to side on html

Tags: html, css, forms

I´ve been trying to put a `<textarea>` side to side with a `<select>` but it´s not working...

It should be like this:

[image: It should be like this]

Comment: Try put Display: inline in both select and textarea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try making the select and text-area `display: inline-block` or my personal preference, use flexbox:

```
form {
  display: flex;
}
```

CSS-Tricks has a really great article on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/